# Hide and blocked status bar on android

Tags: java, android, hide, statusbar

i know that there are many many response about my question , but i precise that i am making application where any interact on status bar are allow. 
So , i want to hide the status bar.
I already use :

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

the status bar disappear at first but when i interact with the view, he come back and i wish it were blocked.

How I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a fullScreen Acivity i. e. You must add these lines in Your OnCreate method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and then `setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);`

Comment: yes but i forget to mean that i want to status bar disappear AND, my action bar (title bar it's same ?) stay , beaucau i will put a disconnect button in

Comment: If you want to hide the Title Bar then use the first line only Dont use second line of getWindow() it will not show Title Bar, But  it will show Status Bar

Comment: yes the icon of status bar become a point , but when i touch one of three , they come back .. there are something who can stay it block definitely ?

Answer (score 1):

> "the status bar disappear at first but when i interact with the view, he come back and i wish it were blocked."

This happens because android is rebuilding views onchange (see the application lifecycle)
I would recommend you to define it in the manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="yourActivityName"
    android:label="your label"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >

</activity>
```

Comment: when i put this, i have my title bar who disappear whereas i would like JUST the status bar..

Comment: maybe try this... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"    or just take a look at the predefined android themes one of them will give you the result you want to achive

Comment: if i put this, i going to have my titleBar who disappear, and i don't want it. I just need to hide/block the status bar